# update data from html table in sql database with php only. table td is using contenteditable attribute

Tags: php, sql

I want to make an archive from inputs that some user stored. Those inputs then output to html table. I want it now to make a option to edit a title of "Naslov poročila" for which i used contenteditable attribute. How can i read out the new value and update in database using only php ? i cant use anything other because teacher allows only php for it. Thank you.
This is how it looks : 
[Look of archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfbNQ.png)

This is what i used to generate that table:

```
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$fetch["vnosiID"].
            "<td contenteditable>".$fetch["naslov"]."</td>".
            "<td>".date('d.m.Y',strtotime($fetch["datum"]))."</td>".
            "<td>".date('d.m.Y',strtotime($fetch["datumDogodka"]))."</td>".
            "<td>".$fetch["ime"].'</td>'.
            "<td contenteditable = 'false' border=0 id='test'><button id='gumb' name='".$fetch["vnosiID"]."'>POSODOBI</a></td>".
            '</tr>';

        }

//name='".$fetch["vnosiID"]." <--- i used this to name every button by number of ID so i could easier check which field to update ...
```

[sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQAHC.png)
"naslov" must update ...
if u need anything else please tell me, i tried few tutorials but none works out for me ..

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to images.

Comment: create a link instead of a button. give it a get values and update the info on a get value